# AngularJS ngModel Directive with select field and ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying to have some code run during the link callback of the ngModel directive using AngularJS on a select field that uses ngOptions.

```
module.directive("ngModel",function(){
    console.log('ng-model called');
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: -1, // give it lower priority than built-in ng-model
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
         console.log('watching');
         scope.$watch(attr.ngModel,function(value){                
            if (value){
                console.log("changing");
            }
         });
       }
     }
});
```

See this fiddle which demonstrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3r3zwLj/3/

The first select field is populated using ng-options, while the second has its options explicitly written out in html.  If you open up the console, you can see that you only see the "changing" message when you change the second select field.  Changing the first does nothing.

You'll also notice immediately that you only see 'ng-model called' and 'watching' once, even though there are two fields with ng-model on them.

I'd expect ngModel directive to work on both select fields.  What is ng-options doing that is preventing the ngModel from working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the doc for ng-options:
  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

> "Directive Info This directive executes at priority level 0."

If you change the priority of the directive to 0, it runs successfully.  I'm not sure what all the implications are there, but that's why it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ng-options directive, it has another optional ng-model directive, which actually sets the default value to be shown from the options. So in your case, the second list does not have a ng-options directive which makes ng-model look like a regular one. Maybe you can just change the name of your directive.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to update functionality of built in directive, `decorators` are there for this purpose. Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators)